# HTML5 geolocation lat and long coordinates of current GPS position into a variable

Tags: javascript, html, variables, geolocation, scope

I am trying to get the current latitude and longitude values of the user by utilising HTML5's geolocation functionality. After researching and trying to get an answer from other questions here on StackOverflow I seem to still be misunderstanding the concept of accessing a global variable. Everything I have seen so far makes it look like there is a issue with the scope. The code I am using looks like it is using a function within function. I am currently running the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var currentLat = 0;
var currentLong = 0;

function getPosition() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }
}
function showPosition(position) {
    console.log(position.coords.latitude);
    console.log(position.coords.longitude); 
}

getPosition();
```

This code currently works in the fact that it logs the information to the console. However if I change the code to this it doesn't seem to work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var currentLat = 0;
var currentLong = 0;

function getPosition() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }
}
function showPosition(position) {
    currentLat = position.coords.latitude;
    currentLong = position.coords.longitude; 
}

getPosition();

console.log(currentLat + "," + currentLong);
```

It just returns 0 like I set originally. I have searched a lot on global variables but most of the resources online (including StackOverflow) state that I can access these variables as long as I don't redeclare the variable inside a function (or creating a local scope variable that overrides the global variable).

Comment: You are correct in your scope assessment. However, getCurrentPosition is an asynchronous method with showPosition as your success handler. Therefore, your vars do not have the returned values when console.log is executed.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to gro's comment I found this works:

```
    window.onload = function(){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {  
      window.currentLat = position.coords.latitude;
      window.currentLong = position.coords.longitude;
      window.currentLatLong = new google.maps.LatLng(currentLat,currentLong);
      init();
    });
}

function init() {
    // run code here and reference currentLatLong, currentLat and currentLong
}
```